# bash sed fail in while loop

Tags: bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$2
rname=$1
echo "$(<$fname)" | while read line ; do
    result=`echo "$(<$rname)" | grep "$line"; echo $?`
    if [ $result != 0 ]
    then
        sed  '/$line/d' $fname > newkas
    fi 2> /dev/null
done
```

Hi all, i am new to bash.

i have two lists one older than another. I wish to compare the names on 'fname' against 'rname'. 'Result' is the standard out put which i will get if the name is still available in 'rname'. if is not then i will get the non-zero output.
Using sed to delete that line and re route it to a new file.

I have tried part by part of the code and it works until i add in the while loop function. sed don't seems to work as the final output of 'newkas' is the same as the initial input 'fname'.
Is my method wrong or did i miss out any parts?

Comment: If you just want to fix `sed` then using `double quotes` will do. If you want to learn right way of `scripting`, `sorpigal's` answer will guide you through it. :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Part 1: What's wrong

The reason your `sed` expression "doesn't work" is because you used single quotes. You said

```
sed  '/$line/d' $fname > newkas
```

Supposing `fname=input.txt'` and `line='example text'` this will expand to:

```
sed  '/$line/d' input.txt > newkas
```

Note that `$line` is still literally present. This is because `bash` will not interpolate variables inside single quotes, thus `sed` sees the `$` literally.

You could fix this by saying

```
sed  "/$line/d/" $fname > newkas
```

Because inside double quotes the variable will expand. However, if your `sed` expression becomes more complicated you could run into difficulty in cases where bash interprets things which you intended to be interpreted by `sed`. I tend to use the form

```
sed '/'"$line"'/d/' $fname > newkas
```

Which is a bit harder to read but, if you look carefully, single-quotes everything I intend to be part of the `sed` expression and double quotes the variable I want to expand.

#### Part 2: How to improve it

Your script contains a number things which could be improved.

```
echo "$(<$fname)" | while read line ; do
    :
done
```

In the first place you're reading the file with `"$(<$fname)"` when you could just redirect the stdin of the `while` loop. This is a bit redundant, but more importantly you're piping to `while`, which creates an extra subshell and means you can't modify any variables from the enclosing scope. Better to say

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    :
done < "$fname"
```

Next, consider your `grep`

```
echo "$(<$rname)" | grep "$line"
```

Again you're reading the file and echoing it to grep. But, `grep` can read files directly.

```
grep "$line" "$rname"
```

Afterwards you echo the return code and check its value in an `if` statement, which is a [classic useless construct](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#test).

```
result=$( grep "$line" "$rname" ; echo $?)
```

Instead you can just pass `grep` directly to `if`, which will test its return code.

```
if grep -q "$line" "$rname" ; then
    sed  "/$line/d" "$fname" > newkas
fi
```

Note here that I have quoted `$fname`, which is important if it might ever contain a space. I have also added `-q` to `grep`, which suppresses its output.

There's now no need to suppress error messages from the `if` statement, here, because we don't have to worry about `$result` containing an unusual value or `grep` not returning properly.

The final result is this script

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if grep -q "$line" "$rname" ; then
        sed  "/$line/d" "$fname" > newkas
    fi
done < "$fname"
```

Which will not work, because `newkas` is overwritten on every loop. This means that in the end only the last line in `$fname` was used. Instead you could say:

```
cp "$fname" newkas
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if grep -q "$line" "$rname" ; then
        sed  -i '' "/$line/d" newkas
    fi
done < "$fname"
```

Which, I believe, will do what you expect.

#### Part 3: But don't do that

But this is all tangential to solving your actual problem. It appears to me that you want to simply create a file `newkas` which contains the all the lines of `$fname` except those that appear in `$rname`. This is easily done with the `comm` utility:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort "$fname") <(sort "$rname") > newkas
```

This also changes the sort order of the lines, which may not be good for you. If you want to do it without changing the ordering then using the method @fge suggests is best.

```
grep -F -v -x -f "$rname" "$fname"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your need correctly, you want a file `newaks` which contains the lines in `$fname` which are also in `$rname`.

If this is what you want, using sed is overkill. Use `fgrep`:

```
fgrep -x -f $fname $rname > newkas
```

Also, there are problems with your script:

- you capture the output of `grep` in `result`, which means it will never be exactly 0; what you want is executing the command and simply check for `$?`
- your `echo`es are convoluted, just do `grep whatever thefilename`, or `while...done <thefile`;
- finally, you take the line as is from the source file: the line can potentially be a regex, which means you will try and match a regex in `$rname`, which may yield to unexpected results.

And others.